# access the current color of movieclip in colPicker as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

i am using a Red movie Clip and i have a col Picker. when this red movie Clip load on the stage, i want to change the color(red) of col Picker. I am using following Code:

```
colorBox.selectedColor = red_clip.transform.colorTransform;
```

How the Access the color.Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading a MovieClip that is like square and monochrome?
I can't imagine the use case for this.

Anyway, to get the color of a given pixel of a movieclip that is on stage, you will need to render it in a bitmap first.

```
// Imagining you want the color that is at (x_offset, y_offset) in your loaded movieclip.

// create a bitmapdata and draw the loaded clip in it
var bdata : BitmapData = new BitmapData(red_clip.width, red_clip.height, true, 0);
bdata.draw(red_clip);

// read pixel from the bitmapdata to get a color
var color : uint = bdata.getPixel(x_offset, y_offset);
var color_with_alpha : uint = bdata.getPixel32(x_offset, y_offset); // you can also get alpha if you want

// Change color in picker
colorBox.selectedColor = color;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967166/get-the-color-of-movieclip Did you ask the same question yesterday?